# Can Timefold address this scenario? If yes, how?

Tags: timefold

I came across timefold when I was searching for below scenario. Could you provide some guidance as there are multiple planning elements? Could this be addressed using timefold? If so, possible approach with some examples will be great.

Let's say there is a program that starts 1/1/2023 and planned duration of 6 months. This program contains say 10 projects that has some dependency among them. Each project has multiple phase, let's call them as Plan, Design, Execute and Deploy with planned effort for each phase. For each phase there is a list of skillsets required. On the other side, there are engineers with different skillset and availability.

a. Start sequencing projects based on dependency.

b. For each task, assign multiple engineers having required skills. It is possible that engineer may not have all skills required but the combination of engineers need to meet all the skills required for the project phase. Also, consider their availability (say 8 work hrs per day) and vacation.

Determine optimal plan how the program can be executed completing all projects on/before time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Timefold can do this. We have a [project job scheduling](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/use-cases-and-examples/use-cases-and-examples.html#projectJobScheduling) example that you can adapt to your needs. (It is very generic, originally based on a research competition.) You can find this example, and many others, among the examples in [Timefold Solver](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/tree/main/examples).